# A local computation of the Galois group of a polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

The following theorem was proved by van der Waerden in his book on algebra.
His proof used a factorization of a multivariate polynomial.
A paper on the computations of Galois groups said it could be proved by a method of algebraic number theory. I tried to prove it.
I thought about using Hensel's lemma but could not follow through.
I also thought about using a decomposition group but could not follow through either.
How can it be proved?

**Theorem**
Let $A$ be a unique factorization domain.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $f(X)$ be a monic polynomial in $A[X]$.
Supppose $f(X)$ has no multiple root in a splitting field of $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $f(X)$ over $K$.
Let $p$ be an irreducible element of $A$.
Let $F$ be the field of fractions of $A/pA$.
Let $g(X)$ be the reduction of $f(X)$ with respect to $pA$.
Suppose $g(X)$ has no multiple root in a splitting field of $F$.
Let $H$ be the Galois group of $g(X)$ over $F$.
Then $H$ can be embedded in $G$.

Comment: This is sometimes known as "Dedekind's theorem"; that keyword should return some results.

Comment: @Qiaochu Thanks. I found an article "Tate's Proof of a Theorem of Dedekind". This uses a decomposition group as I suspected. The ground ring of this article is the ring of rational integers. However, by localizing at the prime ideal $pA$, I think the same method can be applied to the above theorem.

Comment: The proof is given in a generalized form by my answer to [this question][1]. 

[1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111850/a-galois-group-problem