# $\frac{3}{2}$-generated groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Is there a special name for groups $G$ with the following property?

> For every $g \in G \setminus \{1\}$ there is some $h \in G \setminus \langle g \rangle$ with $G = \langle g,h \rangle$.

Which symmetric groups have this property? (I have already checked with a program that $S_3,S_5,S_6,S_7,S_8,S_9$ have this property. $S_4$ does not have this property.)

*Edit.* $S_n$ has this property for all $ n \neq 2$ (see the accepted answer). Is there a proof for this in English?

Comment: Why not $S_4$??

Comment: In $S_4$ it doesn't work for $g=(1,2)(3,4)$.

Comment: It is known that all finite simple groups have this property: see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/) Apparently this property is called 3/2-generated.

Comment: Thank you Derek! Unfortunately my google skills do not help me out here: How to get information about 3/2-generated groups? (In particular, concerning the symmetric groups.)

Comment: I found some links by googling. See for example [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNirm--tPTAhWGCywKHUROCCoQFghbMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni-bielefeld.de%2F~baumeist%2Fwop2017%2Fposter%2FHarper_poster.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEHMwAwbOWXw6i3AT3caCRbHXSZKw&sig2=MwuiYZDquJ0iLhBxJcFglg) and the references given. The main question there is: *Which finite groups are $\frac{3}{2}$-generated?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such groups are called *$\frac{3}{2}$-generated*. According to Breuer, Guralnick and Kantor, a finite group is conjectured to be $\frac{3}{2}$-generated, if and only if every proper quotient is cyclic. For the symmetric group $S_n$ this is true if and only if $n=4$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235196/quotient-groups-of-a-finite-symmetric-group). Hence we obtain:

**Conjecture:** The symmetric group $S_n$ for $n\neq 4$ is $\frac{3}{2}$-generated.

This was proved for $S_n$, $n\neq 4$ by [G. Y. Binder](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ivm&paperid=3408&option_lang=eng) in $1968$. 
A proof in English is available by I. M. Isaacs and Thilo Zieschang in [Generating Symmetric Groups](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~potocnik/poucevanje/SeminarI2013/T13-JordanovIzrek.pdf), $1995$.

Comment: Thank you. That $S_n$ is $\tfrac{3}{2}$-generated for $n>4$ has been apparently proven by G. Ya. Binder, *The bases of the symmetric group*. But that article is in Russian, so that I cannot read it. I have only found that reference in Brenner, Wiegold, *Two-generator groups, I*.

Comment: I believe I.M. Isaacs wrote an article in the AMM a few years ago with a proof of this fact (for $S_n$). I'll try and dig up the reference.

Comment: Yes, it is: Isaacs, I.M.; Zieschang, Thilo. *Generating Symmetric Groups.* AMM **102** (1995) 734-739

Comment: @SteveD Many thanks! I have added the links.