# Classification of groups whose any non-trivial element can be associate to another to generate all

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

**Question**: What are the groups (possibly infinite)  $G$ satisfying the following property?  $$ \forall g \in G \setminus \{ e  \} \ \exists g' \in G \text{ such that } \langle  g,g' \rangle = G.$$

*Examples*: the cyclic groups, the groups $C_p \times C_p$, and more generally $C_p \rtimes C_q$ with $p,q$ primes.

Comment: An immediate observation is that for any $1\ne H\le G$ you must have $G/N$ cyclic where $N=\langle H^G\rangle$. This is because for $g\in H\setminus\{1\}$ we have $\langle g,g'\rangle\le \langle g^G,g'\rangle$ so $G/N$ is a quotient of $G/\langle g^G\rangle$ which is generated by the image of $g'$. This means either $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup (that is $G$ is monolithic) or the socle of $G$ is a product of two cyclic groups.

Comment: in the first case of course, if the monolith is central, then $G$ is abelian, so cyclic

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263690/frac32-generated-groups?rq=1 for lots of information. For finite groups there’s a conjecture that the restriction in @RobertChamberlain’s comment (every proper quotient is cyclic) is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Very nice! These groups are called $\frac{3}{2}$-generated, very chic! For $n \neq 4$, every symmetric group $S_n$ is so. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/59287/34538) contains references proving that every finite simple group is  so.

Comment: Something very similar holds for almost all $2$-generator groups ("random" $2$-generator groups, in the sense of Gromov): for all $g\in G$, either $\langle g, g'\rangle$ is free for all $g'\in G$, or there exists some $g'\in G$ such that $\langle g, g'\rangle=G$. This follows from Theorem B.3 of Kapovich and Schupp, *Genericity, the Arzhantseva-Ol'shanskii method and the Isomorphism Problem for One-Relator Groups*,  Math. Ann. (2005) 331: 1. [doi](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-004-0570-x), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210307).

Comment: (Incidentally, I don't know if the first case in my comment can ever happen: if there can exist $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ such that $\langle g, g'\rangle$ is free for all $g'\in G$. If you could prove that this never happened for all the groups in my comment then that would be an interesting result. Seriously. Especially as the property has been studied for finite groups.)

Comment: @user1729: It can happens. Jeremy Rickard shown the following paper of Guba (as a comment in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/324060/34538)): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00969195?LI=true

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux That's not what my comment was saying. I was asking the following: Let $G$ be a "random" 2-generated group, as defined in the Kapovich-Schupp paper (these groups are always infinite, torsion free, hyperbolic, etc.). Does there exist some $g\in G$ such that for all $g'\in G$ the subgroup $\langle g, g'\rangle$ is free? If not, this implies that almost every group satisfies the property in your question.

Comment: @user1729: I see, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Many such groups have a similar structure that you mentioned as examples. (This is not a complete answer to your question.)

> **Claim**. An *Artinian* group $G$ with *non-trivial center* satisfying
>   $$ \forall g \in G \setminus \{e\},\ \exists g' \in G \text{ such that } \langle g, g' \rangle = G \tag{$\ast$} $$
>   is a cyclic group or the semidirect product of cyclic groups.

*Proof*. Let us assume that $G$ is not cyclic and prove $G$ is the semidirect product of cyclic groups. Namely, we shall prove that there are elements $a, b \in G$ such that 
$$\langle a, b \rangle = G,\ \langle a \rangle \unlhd G,\ \text{ and } \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{ e \}.$$ Take a random central element $a_0 \neq e$ of $G$. By $(\ast)$, there is an element $b_0$ of $G$ such that $\langle a_0, b_0 \rangle = G$. If $\langle a_0 \rangle \cap \langle b_0 \rangle = \{ e \}$ then there is nothing to do. If not, then take $e \neq a_1 \in \langle a_0 \rangle \cap \langle b_0 \rangle$. Again, by $(\ast)$, there is an element $b_1$ of $G$ such that $\langle a_1, b_1 \rangle = G$. Repeating this process, we have a descending series
$$ \langle a_0 \rangle \ge \langle a_1 \rangle \ge \langle a_2 \rangle \ge \cdots $$
*if* $\langle a_n \rangle \cap \langle b_n \rangle \neq \{ e \}$ for all $n \ge 0$. Since $G$ is artinian, there is some index $i \ge 0$ such that $\langle a_i \rangle = \langle a_{i+1} \rangle$. Then
$$ \langle a_i \rangle = \langle a_{i+1} \rangle \le \langle a_i \rangle \cap \langle b_i \rangle \le \langle a_i \rangle$$
and we have $\langle a_i \rangle \le \langle b_i \rangle $. However, as $G = \langle a_i, b_i \rangle \le \langle b_i \rangle$, we have $G$ is cyclic which condradicts to our assumption. Therefore, $\langle a_n \rangle \cap \langle b_n \rangle = \{ e \}$ for some $n \ge 0$.