# Determine all quotient group of $S_3$ and the corresponding homomorphism image.

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

The group $S_3$ has only three normal subgroups. They are $S_3, \{e\}$, and $\lbrace e,(1 \ 2 \ 3), (1\ 3 \ 2) \rbrace$ where $e$ is the identity element of $S_3$. Determine all quotient groups of $S_3$ and the corresponding homomorphism image.

Here is what I tried.

Let $H=\lbrace e,(1 \ 2 \ 3), (1\ 3 \ 2) \rbrace$. Then, for the quotient group $S_3/H$, I found $S_3/H=\lbrace H, (2\ 3)H \rbrace$.
But I stuck for the next and for the quotient group $S_3/e$ and $S_3/S_3$.
Any idea?
Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: For the general case of $S_n$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235196/quotient-groups-of-a-finite-symmetric-group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homomorphic images are $\{e\},S_3$ and $\Bbb Z_2$.  Note that there is only one $2$-element group.

Comment: sorry, i'm confused on your statement.

Comment: how can it be $\mathbb{Z}_n$ since it on symmetric group?

Comment: $S_3/H\cong\Bbb Z_2$.  The quotient of a $6$ element group by a $3$ element group is a $2$ element group.  And there's only one.

Comment: What about my answer?

Comment: Is it on wrong way? Please show me to the right track. What about the quotient group $S_3/e$?

Comment: Ok.  Notice your quotient has $2$ elements.  That's correct.

Comment: $G/e\cong G$ for any $G$.  And $G/G\cong e$.

Comment: So, the only quotient group is as I show in the post, right? And now, how to find the homomorphism image?

Comment: So, there are three quotient group, right?

Comment: The homomorphic images are the quotient groups.  Where the homomorphisms are the canonical projections.

Comment: Ok, so? There are three quotient group?

Comment: Yes.  As I mentioned.

Comment: Great. Thanks for help, Sir.