# Galois extension corresponding to $S_n$

Tags: galois-theory

Given a positive integer $n$. How to find a Galois extension $K/F$ such that $Gal(K/F)=S_n$?

With the restriction $F=\mathbb{Q}$, this is the [Inverse Galois Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Symmetric_and_alternating_groups). But if we are allowed to choose $F$ and $K$, I suspect there is a simpler example.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

How about $F=\mathbb Q(T_1, \ldots, T_{n-1})$ and $K=\mathbb F[X]/(X^n+T_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\ldots +T_0)$?

Comment: Why is $K$ Galois over $F$? Maybe the construction needs to be done several times to get a Galois extension. Or simply take $K$ to be the splitting field of $X^n+T_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+T_0$ over $F$?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the concept of general polynomials? you can read the online course notes by J.S.Milne : http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf, here you will find your answer clearly.