# Biggest splitting field degree given a polynomial of degree n

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

It's a well know fact that, given $f(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ with $\deg(f) = n$, and being $\mathbb{L}$ its splitting field, we have that $[\mathbb{L}:\mathbb{K}] \leq n!$

What I'd like to know are some examples for which the equality holds.
As far as I know:

- $n=2$ is trivial
- $n=3$ we can take $f(x) = x^3-2$  (am I correct?)

What about $n > 3$?  Can someone give me some examples please? Is there a way to construct polynomials of any degree which satisfy what I'm asking for?

Thank you!

Comment: If you know something about Galois Theory this colud be usefull to you! (The order of the galois group is equal to the degree of the extension over the base field...) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The splitting field of the *generic* polynomial of degree $n$: $\,x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$ has degree $\,n!\,$ over the field $K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. Its Galois group is $S_n$.

Using this fact, Galois proved  the impossibility to solve the general equation of degree $n$ as soon as $n\ge 5$.

*Numerical examples*

- The splitting field of $x^3-2$ is $K=\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]2,\omega)$, where $\omega=\mathrm e^{\frac{2\mathrm i\pi}3}$. As $[K:\mathbf Q]=6$, $\,\lvert\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbf Q)\rvert=6$.
- The polynomial $x^5-6x+3$ is irreducible, by Eisenstein criterion, hence its Galois group has order divisible by $5$. By Cauchy's theorem is contains an element of order $5$. As we're in $S_5$, it as actually a $5$-cycle.
  On another hand, elementary analysis shows it has three real toots and two complex roots. These are conjugates, so that the Galois group contains a transposition.

One shows that renumbering the roots adequately, one may suppose the Galois group contains the cycle $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ and the transposition $(1\,2)$. But it is a classical result on symmetric groups that these two permutations generate $S_5$. Hence the Galois group is $S_5$.

- For quartic polynomials, a more technical example: $x^4-4x^2+x+1$  is irreducible, of discriminant $19\cdot103$. Its Ferrari resolvent is the polynomial $y^3+4y^2-4y-17$ and it is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$. A theorem states that is the discriminant is not a square and the resolvent is irreducible, the Galois group is $S_4$.

By definition the Ferrari resolvent of a quartic equation with (complex) roots $x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4$ is the polynomial in $y$:
$$\bigl(y-(x_1x_2+x_3x_4)\bigr)\bigl(y-(x_1x_3+x_2x_4)\bigr)\bigl(y-(x_1x_4+x_2x_3)\bigr).$$

Comment: I know, what I'm asking for is for some examples of these "generic polynomial" of degree $< 3$ such that extending $\mathbb{K}$ (in this case $\mathbb{Q}$) with thier roots we have obtain an extension of degree $n!$

Comment: @Klest Dedja: I've updated my answer with numerical examples.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there are two separate ideas:

1. If you have $K\subset L$ fields and take $a\in L$ such that $\exists f\in K[X]$ such that $f(a)=0$. Then if you construct the minimal polynomial of $a$ which we will denote by $irr_a$, i.e. a polynomial that is irreducible in $K[X]$ and has $a$ a root, you have that $[K(a):K]=\deg irr_a$ where a basis in $K(a)$ as a vector space over $K$ is given by $\{1,a,\dots a^{\deg(irr_a)}\}$. All other polynomials $g$ in $K[X]$ that have $a$ as a root have $\deg(g)\geq \deg(irr_a)$. For example, you shall observe that: $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2):\mathbb Q]=3$ where the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3] 2$ is $X^3-2$.
2. If you have $K\subset L$ fields and take $f\in K[X]$, then $[K(f):K]>\deg(f)$. If you take $f=x^3-2\in\mathbb Q(X)$, $\mathbb Q(f)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt [3]2, a, b)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt [3]2, a)$ where $a,b$ are the other two complex roots of $f$ and $[\mathbb Q(f):\mathbb Q]=6>3$. $[K(f):K]=\deg(f)$, if the extension is Galois, i.e. if it is normal (all the roots of $f$ are in $K$) and separable ($f$ has no multiple roots).

Comment: I know, what about a polynomial with $deg(f) = n > 3$ such that $[\mathbb{Q}(f): \mathbb{Q}] = n!$   ?    Can you give me some examples?