# Under what conditions $[E:F]=\deg(f)$ where $f\in F[x]$ and $E\setminus F$ is a field extension

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have learned a lemma that says

> For every polynomial $f\in F[x]$ there exists a finite field extension $E\setminus F$ where $f$ is splitted in $E$ and $$[E:F]\leq \deg(f)$$

I wanted to know under what conditions there's an iqualuty $$[E:F]=\deg (f)$$
I guess that a necessary and sufficient condition is that $f$ is irreducible in $F$ and I wanted to ask wheather it's correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually the correct statement is that if $E$ is a splitting field of $f$ of degree $n$, then $[E:F] \leq n!$

Comment: Moreover, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149743/biggest-splitting-field-degree-given-a-polynomial-of-degree-n