# Why these 'elementary' facts do not solve the Inverse Galois Problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Since every finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{n}$ and according to the first answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n) there is always (for all $n\geq 1$) a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ with $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\cong S_{n}$, doesn't the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory gives a positive answer to the Inverse Galois Problem?

Where is the obvious point I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: How would you go from an extension giving the symmetric group to one giving a specified subgroup?

Comment: If $G\le S_n$ then, with $K$ as in your question, the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory implies that
$$Gal(K/F)\simeq G,$$ where $F$ is the fixed field of $G$. Adjusting the situation to replace $F$ with $\Bbb{Q}$ is the challenge.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If $H\subset \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ then the set elements elements of $K$ fixed by $H$ is a field $k$, and you get $$H\cong\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)\,.$$

But the inverse Galois question is seeking $k$ so that $H\cong \mathrm{Gal}(k/\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: @Shoutre Don’t worry, it’s a fair question and a common misinterpretation (of either the main theorem of Galois theory or the inverse problem).