# $G$ is a finite group. Show that there are finite extensions $F/\mathbb{Q}$ and $E/F$ such that $E/F$ is Galois with Galois group $G$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm self studying fields and Galois theory, and I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that there are finite extensions $F/\mathbb{Q}$ and $E/F$ such that $E/F$ is Galois with Galois group $G$.

I'm lost on how to show this. How should I get started on this problem?

Thanks in advance, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Going by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n), for any $n$ there is a finite Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ with Galois group $S_n$. Let $E$ be such an extension for $S_{|G|}$. Now use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory together with the fact that any group is isomorphic to a subgroup of the full group of permutations of its elements.